# change dir attribute according to a dynamic variable

Tags: html, angular

I would like to change the `dir` attribute according to a dynamic variable .

```html
  <input 
                [id]="'element'+i" 
                [(ngModel)]="parent.firstName" 
                class="form-control input-lg" 
                [name]="'parent.firstName'"
                [attr.aria-describedby]="'lblfirstName'+i" 
                pattern="^[a-zA-Z\-\u0590-\u05FF ]+$" 
                #firstName="ngModel" 
                [required]="i == 0"
                [ngModelOptions]="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"
/>
```

I have tried adding `dir={{dynamicVariable}}` to the `input` attributes but no success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to bind the dir attribute, you can add this to the template.html:

```
<input type="text" [dir]="myDir" />
```

and in your component.ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  myDir = "rtl";
}
```

Comment: so for some reason `dir=ltr` works as expected, but `[dir]="myDir"` isn't. and I know for sure that `myDir` is changing its value . But, the value is being changed after a button click was fired. Maybe that's the reason?

Comment: can you show a stackblitz that it doesnt work for? here is a stackblitz which works with the suggested way of binding:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pzxwxy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts